# ASP.net MVC5 Showing data from a joined ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this ViewModel here called UsersViewModel. It is joined with a table called userextended.

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser aspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public AspNetUsersExtended aspUsersExtended { get; set; }
}
```

I am stuck on what I should do that join the tables and push them out to the view.
This is my controller:

```
private ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    private List<UsersViewModel> GetUsers()
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext);
        List<UsersViewModel> uvml = new List<UsersViewModel>();
        AspNetUsersExtended[] usersExtended = dbContext.AspNetUsersExtended.ToArray();

        return uvml;
    }
```

I've seen some examples where they do sql query joins but I'm wondering if the viewmodel can already join it automatically like in the model?

UPDATED:

```
@model IEnumerable<ManagementStudio.ViewModels.UsersViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Users</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.aspNetUsers.Id</p>
    <p>@item.aspNetUsers.Email</p>
    <p>@item.aspUsersExtended.Notes</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's relation between ApplicationUser and AspNetUsersExtended, you can use linq2sql way to join both collection like so

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext);
List<UsersViewModel> uvml = (from user in userStore.Users
                                 join ext in dbContext.AspNetUsersExtended
                                 on user.X equals ext.X
                                 select new UsersViewModel
                                 {
                                     aspNetUsers = user,
                                     aspUsersExtended = ext
                                 }).ToList();

return uvml;
```

Didn't have machine with me to test it out at the moment, hope it helps.